# How to use group by in sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
           t1.name as t1_name, 
           MAX(t1.unit) as t1_unit, 
           MAX(t1.id_producer_goods) AS hi_id_producer_goods, 
          t2.name as t2_name 
FROM Table1 t1 
    left join Table2 t2 on t1.id_web_site=t2.id_web_site 
WHERE t1.id='23'  
GROUP BY t1.name
```

When I run the query, I get the following error:

```
Column 'Table2.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained 
in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

How to write this query?

Comment: Do not use DISTINCT and GROUP BY. It is too much...

Comment: @jyparask but me need make group tht get only unique name

Comment: @TeopLome If you want unique name than there is no need of using `GroupBy` for name .http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-use-group-by-in-sql-server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, either use an aggregate function with the `t2.name` or add it to the `GROUP BY`, it depends on the desired results you are looking for:

```
SELECT 
  t1.name as t1_name, 
  t2.name as t2_name,
  MAX(t1.unit) as t1_unit, 
  MAX(t1.id_producer_goods) AS hi_id_producer_goods
FROM Table1 hi 
left join Table2 t2 on t1.id_web_site=t2.id_web_site 
WHERE t1.id='23'  
GROUP BY t1.name, t2.name;
```

The error makes sense, because it has to know which value to select from the `t2.name` for each group of `t1.name`? should it select the `max`, `min`, etc. Otherwise `GROUP BY` it.

Also, remove the `DISTINCT` there is no need for it with `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
t1.name as t1_name, 
MAX(t1.unit) as t1_unit, 
MAX(t1.id_producer_goods) AS hi_id_producer_goods, 
t2.name as t2_name FROM Table1 hi 
left join Table2 t2 on t1.id_web_site=t2.id_web_site 
WHERE 
t1.id='23'  
GROUP BY t1.name,t2.name
```

You need to group by all fields that are not used in AGG functions. etc MAX

Comment: Also removed DISTINCT since that is not nessecary when you are grouping on that column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT 
t1.name as t1_name, 
MAX(t1.unit) as t1_unit, 
MAX(t1.id_producer_goods) AS hi_id_producer_goods, 
t2.name as t2_name FROM Table1 hi 
left join Table2 t2 on t1.id_web_site=t2.id_web_site 
WHERE 
t1.id='23'  
GROUP BY t1.name,t2.name
```

You are using aggregate function with 2 columns then you need to group on both columns

Comment: @Key Nelson: Sorry I was not seen that you have posted same answer, because there is some minor seconds time difference.

Comment: hehe i think we all answered the same time :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need DISTINCT keyword here .

```
           SELECT 
           t1.name as t1_name, 
           MAX(t1.unit) as t1_unit, 
           MAX(t1.id_producer_goods) AS hi_id_producer_goods, 
          t2.name as t2_name 
FROM Table1 t1 
    left join Table2 t2 on t1.id_web_site=t2.id_web_site 
WHERE t1.id='23'  
GROUP BY t1.name,t2.name
```